React Hook Form crashes when passing in { control } object as parameter to nested form
I want to write a MUI form component for a small datatype with a few fields to be nested inside another parent form component which creates a { control } for a parent data type which contains in one of its fields an object of the child data type. I am doing this by creating { object }  via useForm<ParentDataType>({ ... });, and pass this object to my child component as a parameter.
This all works nicely when I build the child component directly from MUI components (<TextField /> inside render function of a <Controller>, to be precise).
However, when I build the child component from a third custom component (TextFormInput), also taking { control }, it crashes at startup with:
Uncaught TypeError: control._names is undefined deep inside the library, which in the OK case appears to contain various data about all fields of ParentType and mounts to a particular one.
Seems it looses some sort of context when there { control } is passed through an intermediate component layer. Would love to understand what needs to change so I can reuse my TextFormInput component also in MoneyForm.
Parent and Child Types
type ExpenseT = {
    purpose: string;
    amount: MoneyT;
}
type MoneyT = {
    magnitude: number;
    currency: string;
}

Parent Form Component
github
const ExpenseForm = (): ReactElement => {
    const { control, handleSubmit } = useForm<ExpenseT>({ defaultValues: defaultExpense });

    const onSubmit = (data: ExpenseT) => {
        console.log(`Expense of ${data.amount.magnitude} ${data.amount.currency} for ${data.purpose}`);
    }

    return (
        ... layout stuff omitted ...
                    <Stack spacing={4}>
                        <TextFormInput
                            control={control}
                            fieldName="purpose"
                            label="Purpose"
                        />
                        <MoneyForm
                            control={control}
                            label="How Much Dash?"
                            fieldName="amount"
                        />
                        <Button onClick={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>SAVE</Button>
                    </Stack>
                
    );
}


Child Form Component - OK CASE
github
const MoneyForm = ({control, fieldName, label}: FormInputPropsT
): ReactElement => (
    
        <Stack>
            <Divider/>
            <Typography variant="subtitle1">{label}</Typography>
            <Grid container direction="row" columnSpacing={2}>
                <Grid item xs={8}>
                    <Controller
                        name={`${fieldName}.magnitude`}
                        control={control}
                        render={({
                           field: { onChange, value },
                           fieldState: { error },
                        }) => (
                            <TextField
                                helperText={error ? error.message : null}
                                error={!!error}
                                onChange={onChange}
                                value={value}
                                fullWidth
                                label="Amount"
                                variant="outlined"
                            />
                        )} />
                </Grid>
                <Grid item xs={4}>
                    <Controller
                        name={`${fieldName}.currency`}
                        control={control}
                        render={({
                                     field: { onChange, value },
                                     fieldState: { error },
                                 }) => (
                            <TextField
                                helperText={error ? error.message : null}
                                error={!!error}
                                onChange={onChange}
                                value={value}
                                fullWidth
                                label="Currency"
                                variant="outlined"
                            />
                        )}/>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </Stack>
);

Child Component - Broken
github
const MoneyForm = ({control, fieldName, label}: FormInputPropsT
): ReactElement => (
    <Box>
        <Stack>
            <Divider/>
            <Typography variant="subtitle1">{label}</Typography>
            <Grid container direction="row" columnSpacing={2}>
                <Grid item xs={8}>
                    <TextFormInput
                        control={{control}}
                        fieldName={`${fieldName}.magnitude`}
                        label="Amount"
                    />
                </Grid>
                <Grid item xs={4}>
                    <TextFormInput
                        control={{control}}
                        fieldName={`${fieldName}.currency`}
                        label="Currency"
                    />
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </Stack>
    </Box>
);


Great. the SECOND I look onto the post, I find my typos in MoneyForm.
passing {{control}} instead of {control} to my TextInputForm. Duhh!
Not that I haven't stared at the code for an hour before writing all this up :-)
Hilarious.
